# jQuery change field when radio is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm setting up a checkout form which contains several payment options. I want that the price can vary depending on a radio button selected. I've found several jQuery examples that do that, yet nothing happens when the user selects one radio button.
Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.2.6.min.js"></script>

<script>

$('input[name=payment]').change(function() {

    switch ($('input[name=payment]:checked').val()) {
    case 'skrill':
        $('#costLabel').text('13.99');      
        break;
    case 'paypal':
        $('#costLabel').text('14.99');
        break;
    default:
        $('#costLabel').text('select your choice');
    }
});

</script>


<form  name="myform" action="" method="post"  >
<br>Please choose Payment method and click on the Buy button: 
<br/>
<p>
<label><input id="skrill" type="radio" checked name="payment">Credit Card &nbsp;<img src="/images/creditcard.png"></label><br>
<label><input id="paypal" type="radio" name="payment">PayPal &nbsp; <img src="/images/paypal.png"></label><br>

</p>

<br/>
 <fieldset>
      <label id="costLabel" name="costLabel">Total price: </label>
 </fieldset>

</form>
```

The expected action is to update the "costLabel" when a radio is selected.
Any idea of what could be the problem?
Thans

Comment: jQuery 1.2.6? Why such an old version

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Radio buttons should have a value attributes. For example:

```
<input id="skrill" value="skrill" type="radio" checked name="payment"> Credit Card
```

Also it makes sense to move `#costLabel` into separate span to keep `Total price` text in place:

```
<label name="costLabel">Total price: <span id="costLabel"></span></label>
```

Finally you don't need to reselect checked radio button with `$('input[name=payment]:checked')` because inside of change handler you can refer the currently one checked with `$(this)`.

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/E9L75/

Answer (score 0):

Enclose your script inside,

```
$(document).ready(function(e)
{
   // Place your script here
});
```

Comment: Please add the reason for doing so.